# creating a tar archive from another with a few files changed

Tags: linux, tar

I have a need to "scrub" a copy of a production backup - it's a very large tar.gz containing a number of very small files that need to be anonymized.   I know I can extract it, overwrite the files, and the compress it again, but that takes a lot of disk space, and introduces a risk on the prod machine.  I know I can

```
tar zxvf myarchive filea fileb filec
```

but then I can't figure out if there's a way of constructing a *new* file with my new copies of them swapped over - in something like

```
tar zxfv --exclude filea fileb filec | concat file, fileb, filec | tar cvfz newarchive
```

Is anything like that possible?    ie can I produce the new archive without having a full sized uncompressed .tar ever appearing on my disk?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but if you used `tar(1)` the runtime would become exponential with the size of the archive. Consider writing a script in a language that has streaming tar support, e.g. Python with `tarfile`, that would allow you to read out the individual files in a stream and then add them to another archive.